# Strange behaviour using println with raw pointer

Tags: rust

I need a binary tree data structure in C, and there is already exist a binary tree implementation in Rust. So I decided to wrap that.

I made a C-compatible struct contains raw pointer to BTreeMap and add some methods that take a pointer to my wrapper struct.

The problem is in module test. The test is passed if I using my methods only, but whenever I put the println! macro between method calls, The test failed.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct my_btree {
    btree: *mut BTreeMap<u64, u64>,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_btree_new() -> *mut my_btree {
    let boxed = Box::new(BTreeMap::<u64, u64>::new());
    let mut ret = my_btree {
        btree: Box::into_raw(boxed),
    };

    &mut ret as *mut my_btree
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_btree_insert(
    btree: *mut my_btree,
    key: u64,
    val: u64,
) -> bool {
    unsafe {
        let mut boxed = Box::from_raw((*btree).btree);
        let contains = (*boxed).contains_key(&key);
        if contains {
            return false;
        }

        (*boxed).insert(key, val);
        println!("{:?}", boxed);
        Box::into_raw(boxed);

        return true;
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_btree_contains(btree: *mut my_btree, key: u64) -> bool {
    unsafe {
        let boxed = Box::from_raw((*btree).btree);
        println!("{:?}", boxed);
        let ret = (*boxed).contains_key(&key);

        Box::into_raw(boxed);

        ret
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_btree_free(btree: *mut my_btree) {
    unsafe {
        let _boxed = Box::from_raw((*btree).btree);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn insert() {
        let map = my_btree_new();
        my_btree_insert(map, 1, 1);
        my_btree_insert(map, 2, 2);
        my_btree_insert(map, 3, 30);
        let err = my_btree_contains(map, 1);
        assert_eq!(err, true);
        println!("???"); // If this line commented out, then test success without error.
        my_btree_free(map);
    }
}
```

when I run the test with below command,

```
$ cargo test -- --nocapture
```

In my terminal,

```
running 1 test
{1: 1}
{1: 1, 2: 2}
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 30}
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 30}
???
error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'
```

But if I comment out the `println!("???");` then test pass without any error.

And if I put println between my_btree_insert calls, it failed in next call. It's weird. Why this happened?

Comment: welcome to undefined behavior, take a seat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several issues.

1. In `my_btree_new`, you construct an instance of `my_btree` on the stack (ie. local to the function) and then return a pointer to it.
2. In `my_btree_insert`, you take your pointer, then construct a `Box` around it. Before returning, you deconstruct the `Box` so that the item won't be freed - but you also have an early return path that does not deconstruct the `Box`. Your test case does not exercise that code path, but I expect it would crash if it did.

Why does it only crash when you insert the `println!`? Simple - the extra function call(s) that are generated trash the area of the stack containing the `my_btree`.

Here are a few suggestions for fixing it up:

- You do not really need the wrapper struct (at least for this basic example). But if you are going to have one, the whole struct should be on the heap, not just the BTree structure.
- You don't need to box/unbox the pointer in every method; it is not adding value and is just increasing the chances you will forget to rebox it in some code path, resulting in a double-free crash. Only re-box it in the `my_btree_free` function.
- You have made all these functions safe with the code inside wrapped in an unsafe block. That's not really correct - the compiler cannot verify that the pointer being supplied is correct, therefore the function is not safe (or putting it another way, a safe function should not crash regardless of the arguments you supply).

Here is a version that works:

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct my_btree {
    btree: BTreeMap<u64, u64>,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_btree_new() -> *mut my_btree {
    let boxed = Box::new(my_btree { btree: BTreeMap::<u64, u64>::new() } );
    Box::into_raw(boxed)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn my_btree_insert(
    btree: *mut my_btree,
    key: u64,
    val: u64,
) -> bool {
    let contains = (*btree).btree.contains_key(&key);
    if contains {
        return false;
    }
    (*btree).btree.insert(key, val);

    return true;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn my_btree_contains(btree: *mut my_btree, key: u64) -> bool {
    (*btree).btree.contains_key(&key)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn my_btree_free(btree: *mut my_btree) {
    let _boxed = Box::from_raw(btree);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn insert() {
        let map = my_btree_new();
        unsafe {
            my_btree_insert(map, 1, 1);
            my_btree_insert(map, 2, 2);
            my_btree_insert(map, 3, 30);
            let err = my_btree_contains(map, 1);
            assert_eq!(err, true);
            println!("???"); // If this line commented out, then test success without error.
            my_btree_free(map);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But this library is intended using in C. In C header file, the struct is defined as `typedef struct my_btree { void *btree; } my_btree;`. is member btree(type is BTreeMap<u64, u64>) safely compatible with C? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @hardboiled You should define the type in the header file as just `struct my_btree;` with no body. This is called an opaque type and it is provided for exactly this kind of situation: when the actual implementation of the type is irrelevant because the interface only uses pointers. In C, all object pointers are layout-compatible (which is not the same as having the same valid bit patterns, but is good enough for code like this).